# Can I buy a theme license once, and activate it on all sites in my network?

Tags: html, wordpress, web, themes, multisite

If I buy, download and install the KnowAll knowledge base theme on my multi site network, can i use it on all my sites on my network without paying for each individual site?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is a single site license so the answer is no. For each site you will have to get a license or contact theme author asking for extended license. 
Hope that will solve your issue. 
Regards